# Semantic UI Search and Local Search Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

I have a simple html where I am trying out the html of the search module of Semantic UI and it just won't work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/javascripts/testing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ui search">
      <div class="ui icon input">
         <input class="prompt" placeholder="Search countries..." type="text">
         <i class="search icon"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="results"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.ui.search')
  .search({
   source: content,
});

var content = [
  { title: 'Andorra' },
  { title: 'United Arab Emirates' },
  { title: 'Afghanistan' },
  { title: 'Antigua' },
  { title: 'Anguilla' },
  { title: 'Albania' },
  { title: 'Armenia' },
  { title: 'Netherlands Antilles' },
  { title: 'Angola' },
  { title: 'Argentina' },
  { title: 'American Samoa' },
  { title: 'Austria' },
  { title: 'Australia' },
  { title: 'Aruba' },
  { title: 'Aland Islands' },
  { title: 'Azerbaijan' },
  { title: 'Bosnia' },
  { title: 'Barbados' },
  { title: 'Bangladesh' },
  { title: 'Belgium' },
  { title: 'Burkina Faso' },
  { title: 'Bulgaria' },
  { title: 'Bahrain' },
  { title: 'Burundi' }
  // etc
];
```

What it should be doing is that once I click the search box, the DOM of ui search should change to ui search focus, and the results div should also change. (I based it off what the DOM should do from this http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#local-search)

It should show the results as the user is typing, but my html file doesn't show anything, but the search bar :(

It should be like this: [image](https://i.imgsafe.org/b857616bbb.png)

Comment: move the declaration of content to be before the setup of the search...

Answer (score 1):

The following code should be self-contained. It seems you must use `document.ready` and then it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>  
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var content = [{
                title: 'Andorra'
            }, {
                title: 'United Arab Emirates'
            }, {
                title: 'Afghanistan'
            }, {
                title: 'Antigua'
            },];

            $('.ui.search')
                .search({
                    type: 'standard',
                    source: content,
                    searchFields: ['title'],
                });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui search">
    <div class="ui icon input">
        <input class="prompt" placeholder="Search countries..." type="text">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```